# Does delete delete every element in a vector and free the memory?

Tags: c++

```
    vector<int>* v = new vector<int>;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        (*v).push_back(i);
    }
    delete v;
```

Do I delete every element of the vector and free the memory? If not how do I free the memory?

Comment: Yes, the destructor of `std::vector` will free up its internal array. But why are you dynamically allocating a `std::vector` in the first place?

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use `new` with standard containers.  There is no need to do so and makes the code less efficient.

Comment: Just do `vector<int> v;`.

Comment: Since `std::vector` is *already* a special kind of smart pointer/container for a dynamic array of objects, having an owning raw pointer to a vector is odd.  Pointless use of pointers.

Comment: Not sure why this got closed as needing details or clarity, seems pretty clear to me what is being asked (it might be a duplicate, but its at least clear imo)

Comment: I agree - the close reason is incorrect.  There is sufficient detail and clarity to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An allocating `new` expression allocates memory, constructs a dynamic object into that memory, and returns a pointer to that object. When you pass such pointer to `delete`, the pointed object is destroyed and the memory is deallocated.

When an instance of a class, such as a vector is destroyed, its destructor is called. The destructor of vector destroys all elements of the vector.

---

Sidenote 1: It's rarely useful to use allocating `new` and `delete`. When you need dynamic storage, prefer to use RAII constructs such as containers and smart pointers instead.

Sidenote 2: You should avoid unnecessary use of dynamic memory in general. It's quite rare to need singular dynamic vector such as in your example. I recommend following instead:

```
std::vector<int> v(100);
std::ranges::iota(v, 0);
```

Sidenote 3: Avoid using `(*v).push_back`. It's hard to read. Prefer using the indirecting member access operator aka the arrow operator instead: `v->push_back`